# OAuth 2.0 RFC 6749 Content-Type application/json is compliant with Spec?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, rfc6749

I have an app which is OAuth2.0 and RFC 6749 compliant.

I need to extend the behaviour now such that a new RP will invoke my `/auth` endpoint and it is expecting a response containing my auth_ref, hence I thought instead of the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, I should use `application/json` in the request. This is for 2 reasons:

1. I dont need to change my existing behaviour of http web redirect with login page response if the request is from a web browser
2. I can extend the system to cater to the new RP that expects a JSON response containing the auth_ref, among other things

Q1. Is this spec compliant? According to my understanding of the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1)

Q2. an alternative I am considering is to just expose a different endpoint `/authz`

Q3. Also considering the possibility of adding a new param to the request on the same `/auth` endpoint. Will this also become non compliant with the spec? or will it be treated as an extension to the spec? Any implications if I extend it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `/auth` is an **authorization endpoint** which is defined in RFC 6749, it is a spec violation to use `application/json` as Content-Type of *requests*.

On the other hand, it is allowed to include additional parameters in *responses*. The following is an excerpt from RFC 6749. You can see `example_parameter` in the response JSON.

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

Like the above, you can include `auth_req` in responses. It is compliant with RFC 6749.

An **authorization endpoint** accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and responds with `302 Found` and `Location` header. A **token endpoint** accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and responds with `200 OK` and `application/json`. See *"[Diagrams And Movies Of All The OAuth 2.0 Flows](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85)"* for details.

Comment: thanks for responding. Unfortunately, for the purposes im considering, I need to maintain backward compatability with my existing `/auth` endpoint which is a web based login, while also allowing for another "mode" of login (another site wants to use my backend for login so I will share json in that response only). Hence I may go down the route of a new endpoint which still talks with `Content Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That way the new endpoint will also be spec compliant but it is a different feature of the system. 

Thanks for the answer, the diagrams and movies are cool!